# Comma Usage In Certain Texts

Tags: commas

Is the comma after "wrote" in this text needed:

> Hello. Your management application was declined due to 3+ grammar mistakes. We suggest you try again, but do not use commas before "because" unless the sentence could have two meanings and you also wrote, "bakery's" in the wrong context.

Why would it be needed/not needed?

Comment: This is a hangover from the days when there was less flexibility of punctuation before direct speech and other quotes. I'd say it's verging on being unacceptable before a non-direct-speech quote like this nowadays.

Comment: I love how whoever wrote this cites grammar mistakes as the reason for a rejected application, while simultaneously committing several faux pas—both stylistic and grammatical—themselves. Lovely irony.

Comment: That comma should have been immediately after "meanings" but it arrived a bit late.

Comment: @AndreasBlass But even if there was a comma after "meanings," does the text still need the comma after "wrote"? And would there definitely be a comma if there were multiple words after "wrote"?

Comment: I woujd not put a comma after "wrote".

Comment: So in any form of that kind of context, you would NEVER put a comma after "wrote"?